# Best practice to continue task after response 200 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get response 200 and after that task to be continued. 
For example in below code i wrote that in Laravel 5.2 after `echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` an sms and email will be sent
Is that best practice?
What's problems and flaws of below codes?

```
      ob_end_clean();
      header("Connection: close\r\n");
      header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
      header("Content-Type: application/json\r\n");
      header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created', true, 201);
      ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
      ob_start();
      $data = [
        "data" => $register['cell_phone']
      ];
      echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      $size = ob_get_length();
      header("Content-Length: $size");
      ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
      flush();            // Unless both are called !
      if (session_id()) session_write_close(); // Added a line suggested in the comment
      $this->sms->send_by($register['cell_phone'],trans('customer.your_activation_code').Crypt::decrypt($register['activation_code']));
      if($request->get('email') !==null)
      {
          $this->email->send_by($request->get('email'),Crypt::decrypt($register['activation_code']));
      }
      sleep(20);
```

Comment: Manually setting session, header data, etc. are not best practices. Laravel has own abstractions for such tasks like managing sessions, returning responses, json data and so on. Please refer to the documentation of Laravel, if learning it is your main objective.

Comment: Also use laravel's response object and laravel's [task queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs) to do this. You can push a  job to laravel to perform a second after the response has been sent.

Comment: i dont want task after response 200 be on queue , i want to task after response Quickly run